# Loess regression goes to negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2, loess

I'm currently trying to fit a loess regression to my dataset (latitudinal distribution of biomasses). I used the following code:

```
ggplot(data=test)+
  geom_point(aes(y=log10(value+1), x=lat, colour=variable), alpha=0.5)+
  stat_smooth(aes(y=log10(value+1), x=lat, colour=variable, fill=variable), size=1, alpha=0.1)+
  scale_y_continuous("Depth-integrated biomass (mgC.m-2)")+
  scale_x_continuous("Latitude", limits=c(-70, 80), breaks=seq(-70, 80, 10))+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(colour = "black"))
```

The problem is that the regression goes below 0 while I have no values below 0...
Is there a way to force the regression not to cross 0 ?
I try changing the "span" value, it's better but some part of the loess curve still goes negative. Xlim=c(0, X) was not good since it cut the curves..

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The loess methods assume an unbounded distribution, so can easily go below 0 if you have data near 0.  One option in to work on the log scale (fit the model to the log of the y-values, then exponentiate the predicted values for plotting, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Why would you set xlim if you want to restrict the y-values?  Either way, though, xlim and ylim are only used to filter the underlying dataset and so that won't solve your problem.  An alternative way to avoid 0 values would be to use a different model: a linear regression shouldn't interpolate negative values if all observed values are positive.  Or, maybe something like a logistic regression would be appropriate for your data?

Adding these types of fits to the data is actually pretty easy, just add `method = glm` and and `family = binomial`, for example, inside `stat_smooth`.